# Call other apps in different port with webpack || react

Tags: reactjs, webpack, micro-frontend

Is there any possible way to call other React apps from WebPack? I'm currently working with micro front-ends, and I need a way to call a project from another one, one micro front-end should call another one. I mean:
Home micro front-end: localhost:8080
Timeline micro front-end: localhost:8081
And I need to display Timeline micro front-end like a SPA in the same Home micro front-end

Is there any possible way to do that using WebPack or something in react?
I need to run all of those, or at least use the same State between them, I'm using IndexdedDB to share the State, so, different port will break the state, all of those should be in the same.

Comment: If you need to share the same local state across services then sounds like perhaps you're over engineering this? To answer the question, your only option to communicate via the client would be AJAX (Webpack is a bundler, so you're barking up the wrong tree).

Comment: I am confused here. We see Webpack (build tool), localhost (address / BE), React (UI / FE). In general though - yes, that's possible. We use Piral for this. https://github.com/smapiot/piral